Sorting records for hierarchical relationships when there is more than one parent column
I have following table wherein 2 (can be more) foreign key columns define self-relationship between records of the table.
[Hierarchical records in my problem dataset]



Id
Name
Parent1__c
Parent2__c




a00Hu000014KBJrIAO
Grand Parent
NULL
NULL


a00Hu000014KBJwIAO
Parent 1
a00Hu000014KBJrIAO
NULL


a00Hu000014KBK1IAO
Parent 2
a00Hu000014KBJrIAO
NULL


a00Hu000014KBK6IAO
Child 1_1
a00Hu000014KBJwIAO
NULL


a00Hu000014KBK7IAO
Grand Child 1_1_1
a00Hu000014KBK6IAO
a00Hu000014KBK1IAO


a00Hu000014KBvaIAG
Child 2_2
NULL
a00Hu000014KBK1IAO


a00Hu000014KBvfIAG
Grand Child 2_2_2
a00Hu000014KBJwIAO
a00Hu000014KBvaIAG


a00Hu000014KBvkIAG
Grand Child 1_1_2
a00Hu000014KBK6IAO
NULL



I have seen many examples of using Recursive CTE in SQL when there is a single foreign key column (Parent ID) that defines hierarchy.
What modifications will be required to Recursive CTE when there are more than 1 (Parent columns) as in the image shown above? An example of RCTE, if possible, would be useful.
I would eventually like these to be sorted by level and the expected end result is as attached below.
[Expected End result]



Id
RecordHierarchyLevel




a00Hu000014KBJrIAO
0


a00Hu000014KBJwIAO
1


a00Hu000014KBK1IAO
1


a00Hu000014KBK6IAO
2


a00Hu000014KBvaIAG
2


a00Hu000014KBvfIAG
3


a00Hu000014KBvkIAG
3


a00Hu000014KBK7IAO
3



Thanks in advance.
I have been able to achieve this using Programming language by making queries record-by-record for immediate children and then adjusting record level and running the queries again for 2nd Parent.
But my production dataset could be huge, a million+ records. Hence, I would like to do this using Recursive CTE if that's the best way to solve this.
Programmatically, I had to resort to C# code to fetch the child records for parent records recursively as I admit that I am not a SQL expert. But it becomes very chatty and too many queries need to be fired for a larger dataset. I feel that perhaps Recursive CTE or some other native SQL way (Stored procedure or something) may be written to accomplish this.
Using a Recursive CTE with one column I was able to achieve the following result
With Children 
AS (
    SELECT 
        Id,
        Name,
        Parent1__c,
        Parent2__c,
        0 AS Level
    FROM CustomSelfRel__c
    WHERE Id = 'a00Hu000014KBJrIAO' AND NSPRemoved IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        T.Id,
        T.Name,
        T.Parent1__c,
        T.Parent2__c,
        Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM CustomSelfRel__c AS T
    JOIN Children  C ON C.Id = T.Parent1__c
) SELECT
    *
FROM
    Children;

I have run this on Azure SQL DB using one Parent column Parent1__c. But I don't know how to build this using two columns Parent1__c and Parent2__c.

The problem with multiple parents is that they can introduce ambiguities. When a child has parents at two different levels, what level does the child belong at? Start by thinking about that and then specifying what rules you want to follow. Don't just expect there to be one simple answer.

Are these multiple parent columns simply a composite key (in which case @Damien_The_Unbeliever's concerns don't apply) - or does it mean a single node/element can point to two separate other nodes? (in which case, it's up to you how you should handle that... not us; we don't know your data).

Thank you all for responding, I think I got the answer, posting the same below. Let me know if I am missing something Damien. @DaleK I will also remove the images as suggested above from the original post. Dai , yes, there are multiple parent columns.

I am able to get the desired result by modifying JOIN in recursive part of the CTE as follows.
With Children 
AS (
    SELECT 
        Id,
        0 AS Level
    FROM CustomSelfRel__c
    WHERE Parent1__c IS NULL and Parent2__c IS NULL AND NSPRemoved IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        T.Id,
        Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM CustomSelfRel__c AS T
    JOIN 
        Children C1 
    ON 
        (
            C1.Id = T.Parent1__c
            OR
            C1.Id = T.Parent2__c
        )
        AND
        NSPRemoved IS NULL
) SELECT
    Id,
    max(Level) AS RecordHierarchyLevel
FROM Children
Group BY Id

